# Load .conf file in .scala build definition

Tags: scala, sbt, config, typesafe-config

I'm trying to load a configuration file from `project/distribution.conf` into my `.scala` build definition setting through typesafe config library, although this file exists, this library fails to load it:

```
distributionFile <<= (baseDirectory in ThisBuild)(_ / "project" / "distribution.conf")
```

throw `ConfigException`. But other file `version.properties` was loaded perfectly, although i work with it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i've solved the problem. `ConfigFactory.load(path)` was expecting a relative path, but i coundn't find any method on `File` which could return it. But in `ConfigFactory` there is another method `parseFile` which expects a `File`, so setting is very easy:

```
distributionFile <<= (baseDirectory in ThisBuild)(_ / "project" / "distribution.conf"),
distributionConf := ConfigFactory.parseFile(distributionFile.value)
```